# How to git init in a shared sub-folder on a network drive

Tags: git

I'm unable to git init in a sub-folder that I have read, write, read&execute, modify and list folder content access to.

The path is located on a shared network drive. I do not have access to the folder's parent, although I can access the root folder. I'm using git bash.

The error that appears when trying to git init in the shared sub-folder:

```
$ git init
fatal: unable to get current working directory: No such file or directory
```

The error that appears when trying to git init in the root folder:

```
$ git init
Error: Current working directory is a virtual Cygwin directory which does
not exist for a native Windows application.
Can't start native Windows application from here.
```

If I try to cd into the parent folder:

```
$ cd ..
bash: cd: ..: Permission denied
```

Comment: Are you using Git for Windows or Cygwin's Git?

Comment: I am using git for windows.